# Creating queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, compiler-errors, echo

I have to write 2 queries from postgreSQL against the world database. Right now I have an error when I compile my program and I cant figure out why. The 2 queries that I am working on are

```
1. Find the district and population of all cities named Springfield. 
   Sort results from most populous to least populous. (3 results)
2. Find the name, district, and population of each city in Brazil (country code BRA). 
   Order results by city name alphabetically. (250 results)
```

I then have to print out the results in a table. I am having some issues with this part of my program, the part where I have to print out the results. I believe I have the right SELECT statements to get the correct information, I am just confused on how to display the information in a table. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is my code that I have.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<form method = "POST" action ="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<table>
    <tr><td>Select Query</td><td><select name="query">
    <option value="1">Query 1</option>
    <option value="2">Query 2</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
</tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="execute" value="Generate" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
    include("public_html/secure/database.php");
    $con = ph_connect(HOST." ".DBNAME." ".USERNAME." ".PASSWORD);
    if(isset($_POST["execute"])){

    switch($_POST["query"]){

            case 1:
                    $q = "SELECT district, population FROM lab2.city WHERE (city = 'Springfield') ORDER BY population DESC";
                    $result = pg_query($q) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
                    break;

            case 2:

                   $q = "SELECT name, district, population FROM lab2.city WHERE (country_code = 'BRA') ORDER BY name";      
                    $result = pg_query($q) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());                                      
                    break;
            }

                    echo "<table>\n";
                    while($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
                            echo "\t<tr>\n";
                            foreach($line as $col_value){
                                    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
                            }
                    echo "\t</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>\n";

            pg_free_result($result);
            pg_close($con);


?>

</body>
</html>
```

The error that I am getting right now when I use the command php lab2.php is

Here is an example of the correct output for the first query.

```
district    population
Massachusetts   152082
Missouri    151580
Illinois    111454
```

Comment: `'Query failed: ' pg_last_error()` should be concatenated `'Query failed: ' . pg_last_error()`, `$q = Select` is wrong syntax too.

Comment: @u_mulder okay thanks, but I still get that error after correcting both of those

Comment: Query **must be** a string, please, learn some php basics.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for the clarification. I still have one error and it is 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /students/6/njs2q6/public_html/cs3380/lab2/lab2.php on line 60

Comment: Now that you have edited your OP to put in the quotes have you tested this to see if it will run?

Comment: Check opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score 3):

For a start you should have quotes around the strings in the $q variables;

Example:

```
$q = "Select district, population FROM lab2.city WHERE (city = 'Springfield') ORDER BY population DESC";
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I still get one error though.
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /students/6/njs2q6/public_html/cs3380/lab2/lab2.php on line 60

Comment: I don't have a line 60, the last line I have is line 59 which is the very last line so I am confused haha

Comment: You have also missed a closing bracket for the if statement.
if(isset($_POST["execute"])){
....
 pg_close($con);
 **}**
You should have no syntax errors now.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the visual enhancement :)